# First attempt at React-Native and ios: Error in transformer worker

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a new app folder and have successfully built it, but when I try to launch the emulator I see:

```
Error: Uncaught error in the transformer worker: /Users/jeremylopez/Documents/Projects/ReactNativeProjects/assemblies/node_modules/react-native/packager/transformer.js
    at /Users/jeremylopez/Documents/Projects/ReactNativeProjects/assemblies/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/JSTransformer/index.js:109:33
    at tryCallOne (/Users/jeremylopez/Documents/Projects/ReactNativeProjects/assemblies/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /Users/jeremylopez/Documents/Projects/ReactNativeProjects/assemblies/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
    at flush (/Users/jeremylopez/Documents/Projects/ReactNativeProjects/assemblies/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
[node-haste] Encountered an error while persisting cache:
> Error: Uncaught error in the transformer worker: /Users/jeremylopez/Documents/Projects/ReactNativeProjects/assemblies/node_modules/react-native/packager/transformer.js
>     at /Users/jeremylopez/Documents/Projects/ReactNativeProjects/assemblies/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/JSTransformer/index.js:109:33
>     at tryCallOne (/Users/jeremylopez/Documents/Projects/ReactNativeProjects/assemblies/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
>     at /Users/jeremylopez/Documents/Projects/ReactNativeProjects/assemblies/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
>     at flush (/Users/jeremylopez/Documents/Projects/ReactNativeProjects/assemblies/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
>     at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
>     at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I can't seem to find much on `transformer.js`.

Comment: reload 2-3 times. it should work.

Comment: You are correct.  That is so frustrating

Comment: It happens when you build first time. than after it will work good.